# Xcode 15 Cycle in dependencies detected

Tags: xcode, xcode15

Recently updated my Xcode to 15.0 public release version and getting the following error.

> error: Cycle in dependencies detected, but could not be parsed. Please
> file a bug report with the build transcript and how to reproduce the
> cycle if possible.
>
> Raw dependency cycle trace:
>
> target:  ->
>
> node:  ->
>
> command:  ->
>
> ### node:
> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-fpqiiiuwahekjpfiutbzqrxozzlh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug
>
> ### command: P0:::CreateBuildDirectory
> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-fpqiiiuwahekjpfiutbzqrxozzlh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug
>
> ### node:
> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-fpqiiiuwahekjpfiutbzqrxozzlh/Build/Intermediates.noindex
>
> ### command: P0:::CreateBuildDirectory
> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-fpqiiiuwahekjpfiutbzqrxozzlh/Build/Intermediates.noindex
>
> CYCLE POINT ->
>
> node: / ->
>
> directoryTreeSignature:  ->
>
> directoryContents: / ->
>
> node: /

I have gone through apple thread for the same in [Apple Thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730974) and few stackoverflow threads [How to fix issue of cycle in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888120/how-to-fix-issue-of-cycle-in-dependencies-between-targets-bvlineargrandient-an), [Cycle inside ; building could produce unreliable results: Xcode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709330/cycle-inside-building-could-produce-unreliable-results-xcode-error)

And below is the screenshot of the Build Phases.
Please let me now if any of you were able to solve this build error
[image: And below is the screenshot of the Build Phases. Please let me now if any of you were able to solve this build error.]

Comment: Did found a work around. Had to make DEPLOYMENT LOCATION to NO in Build Settings. This is not right solution but at least its building my project. Had to copy files manually to DEPLOYMENT LOCATION along with its library which is in Derived Data. If any one finds a proper solution, please update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It's likely that when Deployment Location is **Yes** and Installation Build Products Location is **/**, the `Xcode 15.0` throw this error.

I solved it by making the following changes:

> Build Settings -> Deployment

change from

```
Installation Build Products Location "/"
Installation Directory "/usr/local/bin"
```

to

```
Installation Build Products Location "/usr/local/"
Installation Directory "bin"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still getting build error.